# Beginner at Python, math functions for a simple calculator program

Tags: python, string, function, math, integer

I'm making a basic calculator for a programming course and I've read over the PDF's but I can't figure out how to make a function and then use it to print the results of the addition of two numbers. Can someone help me out?

```
def addition(intFirstOperand, intSecondOperand):
    addition = intFirstOperand + intSecondOperand

print ('What mathematical operation would you like to perform? Enter a number:')
print ('1 - addition')
print ('2 - subtraction')
print ('3 - multiplication')
print ('4 - division')

intOperation = input()
intOperation = int(intOperation)

addition = '1'
subtraction = '2'
multiplication = '3'
division = '4'

if intOperation == 1 :
    print ('Please enter the first operand for addition:')
    intFirstOperand = input()
    print ('Please enter the second operand for addition:')
    intSecondOperand = input()
    print addition(intFirstOperand, intSecondOperand)

if intOperation == 2 :
    print ('Please enter the first operand for subtractiom:')
    intFirstOperand = input()
    print ('Please enter the second operand for subtraction:')
    intSecondOperand = input()

if intOperation == 3 :
    print ('Please enter the first operand for multiplication:')
    intFirstOperand = input()
    print ('Please enter the second operand for multiplication:')
    intSecondOperand = input()   

if intOperation == 4 :
    print ('Please enter the first operand for division:')
    intFirstOperand = input()
    print ('Please enter the second operand for division:')
    intSecondOperand = input()
```

Comment: add a `return` statement in your addition function :
`return addition`, and if you're on py3.x then don't forget to convert the string into an integer first(`input()` returns a string in py3x).

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend choosing a different variable name within your function as it can be confusing to have a function and variable with the same name. You can choose to print from within the function, or you can return a value, and then print the returned value outside of the function.

```
def addition(first,second):
    result = int(first) + int(second)
    #print result
    return result

print(addition(5,3)) #prints 8 in python 3.x
```

Alternatively, you can skip assigning a value to 'result' and just return first+second instead.

Answer (score 0):

```
def addition(intFirstOperand, intSecondOperand):
    addition = intFirstOperand + intSecondOperand
    return addition
```

You want to return the value that you calculated. Then your print statements should work.

Comment: I get this Syntax Error:     print addition(intFirstOperand, intSecondOperand): m:\functest.py, line 2418

Comment: @NickDrzewiecki your python version?

Comment: 4.1.7-1 (rev 26990) WING IDE and Python 3.2.3

Comment: if you're using Python3, it needs to be `print(addition(firstOperand, secondOperand))`.

Comment: @NickDrzewiecki use `print()` in py3x.

Comment: Personally, I find the various uses of the word `addition` confusing in your answer. I would use `result` as the local argument, to keep the two uses completely unambiguous. Or just return directory without the local variable.

Comment: @TravisGriggs: `sum` is a Python built-in and a bad choice for an indentifier. Returning *directly* is a better approach.

Comment: Ahh, whoops. I assumed python 2. :( Travis is correct about python 3 notation

Comment: @Johnsyweb. Ouch, facepalm. Fixed. And thanks. The exact ambiguity I was trying to say should be avoided, I traded for a different kind.

Comment: I've changed the format of print and now I get builtins.TypeError: 'str' object is not callable
File "C:\Users\Nick\functiontest.py", line 27, in <module>
  print(addition(intFirstOperand, intSecondOperand))